# find matching word in string using php

Tags: php, regex

i want to search matching word in string like if i have a string

```
"i'm expert in ..."
"i have exposure "
```

if i search "exp" i should return "expert" from first string and "exposure" from second string, if i search "exper" than i should just return "expert" or other words starting "exper"

i'm not looking for position of word but return searched word with in string

i have looked for this all i found strstr(),strrpos() and some others but not what i'm looking for and i'm unable to get it working

Comment: Should it return 'inexpert'?

Comment: start with `preg_match()`

Comment: No,expenditure,experiment if i search "expe"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find all the words starting with `exp` using [`pre_match`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) or [`preg_match_all`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) and the regex:

```
/(exp\w*)/g
```

You can test it [here](http://regex101.com/r/uO9zX7/1).

Answer (score 0):

Very similar to enrico:

`/(exp\w+)/gi`

here http://regex101.com/r/xO9eR7/1